# Yii2 update junction table in many-to-many relationship with Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have 3 table.for example, an article table, a tag table, an article_tag table in the database.
the article and the tag have a N-M relationship.

when I need to add new article, using Yii2's active record's link() method  to save the relationship to the junction table it works fine.

but when I need to update the junction table . if I call the link() method on the article again. it will not work. below is the my code and error info .

```
$tag_ids = Yii::$app->request->post('Article')['tags'];
foreach ($tag_ids as $value) {
   $tag = Tag::findOne($value);
   $model->link('tags', $tag);
}

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `article_tag` (`article_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES (13, 1)
```

Do I need to delete all the data in the junction table then use link() to update it ?? or there are some feature I'm missing in the Yii2?

------------------------update-----------------------------------------

It seems I need to do it with pure sql by myself. The most simple way cross my mind is first delete the data in junction table, then use link() populate the pivot table again. It's simple but will mess up the index. Also the table grows fast. The second way to do this is Read each record then decide keep it or delete it .then add the necessary data.This way make it more complex.More code are needed.

----------------update again I wrote a function ------------------------

```
public function syncTags($new_tag_ids){

    $old_tag_ids = ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->tags, 'id');

    $tag_to_delete = array_diff($old_tag_ids, $new_tag_ids);
    $tag_to_add = array_diff($new_tag_ids, $old_tag_ids);

    if($tag_to_delete){
      //delete tags
      Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
          ->delete('article_tag', ['article_id' => $this->id, 'tag_id' => $tag_to_delete])
          ->execute();
    }

    if($tag_to_add){
      //link new tag assisoated with the article
      foreach ($tag_to_add as $value) {
        $tag = Tag::findOne($value);
        $this->link('tags', $tag);
      }
    }
}
```

It's woking now , but not global applyable .I think it may help people
so post here. Yii needs extension for those kind of work..

Comment: You can try [this extension](https://github.com/arogachev/yii2-many-to-many) for working with many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Or [this one](https://github.com/voskobovich/ManyToManyBehavior). Looks like everyone's written his own many-to-many extension for yii2 :)

Comment: I miss the sync() method in Laravel so much..save me lots of time.

Comment: @Beowulfenator That's not work for me. Cause I 'm using composite primary keys here.

Comment: You can extend it to support composite PKs if you like. I think directly manipulating the tables is the way to do it. Just run two queries - a bulk delete and a bulk insert. I'm sure it's more efficient than doing it one by one. Also, how would it mess up the index?

Comment: Don't use `link()` at all, populate the table with a bulk insert. Also, you're NOT using a composite key for any of original tables, and that's what I meant by "composite keys not supported". So this extension will work in your case.

Comment: I agree with you, just delete then insert is more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Is there spmething like Laravel's `sync`? @Beowulfenator

Comment: @SaidbakR, I have zero experience with Laravel, sorry.

Comment: @Beowulfenator However, `sync` there, automatically delete the absent relation's key and insert the new keys introduced. For example, Shop and Product are many to many related through a conjunction table, pivot, sync will work from the controller's action like the following:

`$shop->products()->sync(request('products'));`

So if you have a multiple select list of the products on the shop view, you could easily remove or add new products to the shop.

Answer (score 2):

Most of time I only use this method. The second solution is working too, but I prefer the first one. I am kind of person who love to solve the problem without help from someone's extension.

```
/**
 * Update categories with the new ones
 * @param  array  $categories [description]
 * @return null
 */
public function updateCategories($categories = [])
{
    $this->unlinkAll('categories', true);

    if ( ! is_array($categories))
        return ;

    foreach ($categories as $category_id)
    {
        $category = Category::findOne($category_id);
        $this->link('categories', $category);
    }

    // alternative solution

    /*
    $old_categories = $this->getCategories()->asArray()->column(); // get all categories IDs
    if ( ! is_array($categories))
        $categories = [];

    $inserted_categories = array_diff($categories, $old_categories);
    $deleted_categories = array_diff($old_categories, $categories);

    foreach ($inserted_categories as $category_id)
    {
        $category = Category::findOne($category_id);
        $this->link('categories', $category);
    }

    foreach ($deleted_categories as $category_id)
    {
        $category = Category::findOne($category_id);
        $this->unlink('categories', $category, true);
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: thks for your reply,but I havn't use php for almost 2 years cause I switch to python..